# How to choose elements out of a matrix randomly weighted

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am pretty new to python and have some problems with Randomness.

I am looking for something similar then [RandomChoice](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html) in Mathematica.
I create a Matrix of dimension let's say 10x3 with random numbers greater 0. Let us call the total sum of every row s_i for i=0,...,9

Later I want to choose for every row 2 out of 3 elements (no repetition) with weighted probability s_ij/s_i
So I need something like this but with weigthed propabilities

```
n=10
aa=np.random.uniform(1000, 2500, (n,3))
print(aa)
help=[0,1,2]
dd=np.zeros((n,2))
for i in range(n):
    cc=random.sample(help,2)
    dd[i,0]=aa[i,cc[0]]
    dd[i,1]=aa[i,cc[1]]
print(dd)
```

Here, additionally speed is an important factor since I will use it in an Montecarlo approach (that's the reason I switched from Mathematica to Python)  and I guess, the above code can be improved heavily

Thanks in advance for any tipps/help

EDIT: I now have the following, which is working but does not look like good gode to me

```
#pre-defined lists 
nn=3
aa=np.random.uniform(1000, 2500, (nn,3))
help1=[0,1,2]
help2=aa.sum(axis=1)
#now I create a weigthed prob list and fill it
help3=np.zeros((nn,3)) 
for i in range(nn):
    help3[i,0]=aa[i,0]/help2[i]
    help3[i,1]=aa[i,1]/help2[i]
    help3[i,2]=aa[i,2]/help2[i]
#every timestep when I have to choose 2 out of 3
help5=np.zeros((nn,2))
for i in range(nn):
    #cc=random.sample(help1,2)
    help4=np.random.choice(help1, 2, replace=False, p=[help3[i,0], help3[i,1], help3[i,2]])
    help5[i,0]=aa[i,cc[0]]
    help5[i,1]=aa[i,cc[1]]
print(help5)
```

Comment: Is it always two elements out of three, or that is just an example (that is, could it be one out of five or four out of six)?

Comment: RTFM! A google search for *numpy random weighted* immediately leads at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html. And `np.random.choice` indeed provided a sample of the given size with given probabilities...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That doesn't fully solve it, though. What the OP needs is a way to sample from _multiple_ categorical distributions, each with a different set of weights. You can  use that function in a loop (or even standard [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) for that matter), but it's not very NumPy-like.

Comment: dear @SergeBallesta 
I was on that HP before and oversaw the fact, that there is a weigthed propability. My mistake!

Comment: @jdehesa, yes, there is still lot of work to do and I am currently working with a lot of help-lists, I add it when it is running. And yes, it is always two out of three in every weight step

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) accepts a weights parameter, so you can simply use that in a loop:

```py
import numpy as np

# Make input data
np.random.seed(0)
n = 10
aa = np.random.uniform(1000, 2500, (n, 3))
s = np.random.rand(n, 3)
# Normalize weights
s_norm = s / s.sum(1, keepdims=True)
# Output array
out = np.empty((n, 2), dtype=aa.dtype)
# Sample iteratively
for i in range(n):
    out[i] = aa[i, np.random.choice(3, size=2, replace=False, p=s_norm[i])]
```

This is not the most efficient way to do things, though, as usually using vectorized operations is much faster than looping. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to sample from multiple categorical distributions at the same time (see [NumPy issue #15201](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15201)). However, since you always want to get two elements out of three, you could sample the element that you want to remove (with inverted probabilities) and then keep the other two. This snippet does something like that:

```py
import numpy as np

# Make input data
np.random.seed(0)
n = 10
aa = np.random.uniform(1000, 2500, (n, 3))
s = np.random.rand(n, 3)
print(s)
# [[0.26455561 0.77423369 0.45615033]
#  [0.56843395 0.0187898  0.6176355 ]
#  [0.61209572 0.616934   0.94374808]
#  [0.6818203  0.3595079  0.43703195]
#  [0.6976312  0.06022547 0.66676672]
#  [0.67063787 0.21038256 0.1289263 ]
#  [0.31542835 0.36371077 0.57019677]
#  [0.43860151 0.98837384 0.10204481]
#  [0.20887676 0.16130952 0.65310833]
#  [0.2532916  0.46631077 0.24442559]]

# Invert weights
si = 1 / s
# Normalize
si_norm = si / si.sum(1, keepdims=True)
# Accumulate
si_cum = np.cumsum(si_norm, axis=1)
# Sample according to inverted probabilities
t = np.random.rand(n, 1)
idx = np.argmax(t < si_cum, axis=1)
# Get non-sampled indices
r = np.arange(3)
m = r != idx[:, np.newaxis]
choice = np.broadcast_to(r, m.shape)[m].reshape(n, -1)
print(choice)
# [[1 2]
#  [0 2]
#  [0 2]
#  [1 2]
#  [0 2]
#  [0 2]
#  [0 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [0 2]
#  [1 2]]

# Get corresponding data
out = np.take_along_axis(aa, choice, 1)
```

One possible drawback of this is that the chosen elements will always be in order (that is, for a given row, you may get the pairs of indices `(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)` or `(1, 2)`, but not `(1, 0)`, `(2, 0)` or `(2, 1)`).

Of course, if you really just need a few samples, then the loop is probably the most convenient and maintainable solution, the second one would only be useful if you need to do this at larger scale.